# Couldn't understand RSpec expectation error

Tags: cucumber, watir, rubymine

I am getting this ExpectationNotMetError in my cucumber/watir test,

How to tell the difference?

RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError:

expected: "Limits as usual \u0393\u00C7\u00F6 Limits in perspective /\u256B\u00C6\u256B\u00E6\u256B\u00F2\u256B\u00A3\u256B\u00F2\u256B\u00AC\u256B\u00D6\u256B\u00F6 \u256B\u2310\u256B\u00A3 \u256B\u00C9\u256B\u00D6\u256B\u00A3\u256B\u00D6\u256B\u00F6 \u256B\u00BA\u256B\u00F1\u256B\u00D6\u256B\u00FF\u256B\u00F2\u256B\u00A3\u256B\u00D6\u256B\u00E1\u256B\u00F6 \u0393\u00C7\u00F6  \u256B\u20A7\u256B\u00E6\u256B\u00FF \u256B\u20A7\u256B\u00E6\u256B\u00AC\u256B\u00D6 \u256B\u00F6\u256B\u00BA\u256B\u00E6\u256B\u00BF\u256B\u00F2\u256B\u00AC"

got: "Limits as usual \u2014 Limits in perspective /\u05D2\u05D1\u05D5\u05DC\u05D5\u05EA\u05D9\u05D4 \u05E9\u05DC \u05D0\u05D9\u05DC\u05D9\u05D4 \u05E7\u05E4\u05D9\u05D8\u05D5\u05DC\u05D9\u05E0\u05D4 \u2014  \u05DE\u05D1\u05D8 \u05DE\u05D1\u05EA\u05D9 \u05D4\u05E7\u05D1\u05E8\u05D5\u05EA"

Comment: It would be nice to show the HTML of the page you are working with and the code that causes the failed assertion.

Comment: Here is the html of the link that i am trying to verify. I want to make sure that link exists in the page as it is.  <a href="/Limits as usual">Limits in perspective /<bdo dir="auto" lang="he">גבולותיה של איליה קפיטולינה —  מבט מבתי הקברות</bdo></a>   I am not providing actual hrefs because of the privacy. Those hewbrew gets translated to unicode characters.

Comment: Ok, so the test expects a string that says "A BCDE" and instead you are only getting a string that says "A DEF" ... so - you're not getting the string that your spec expects. Your expectation is not met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are testing contains "\u 2014" but your test expects the string not to contain that. As a result, the test is failing on the expectation.

To simplify:

expected: "............" got "......2014......"